# Allowing money amounts to be entered into an input with a JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, decimal, currency

I'm using plain vanilla JavaScript and need some help with my regex. Money in the following formats has to be allowed, and in these formats only (with no limit on the number of 0s (tens, hundreds, thousands, etc.) for the dollar amounts allowed):

- $25,000
- $25000
- 25,000
- 25000
- 25000.01
- 25,000.99
- 2000.99
- 50.00
- 50
- 1.95
- 1 .99
- 0.25
- $0.25
- 0.2
- 2.3
- 2000.5
- .75

> var regex = /^\$?.?[1-9][0-9,]*(.[0-9]{0,2})?$/;

Currently, it's not allowing amounts like 0.99 to be entered.

Comment: So...you want to allow only numbers and a single period? With a *maximum* of two numbers following the period, or *always* two numbers following the period?

Comment: here is a great site for testing regex: http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm

Comment: @DavidThomas - $ and commas should be optional. There is no limit to the maximum, it basically just has to be allowed in any format that someone would think of entering from a penny and higher 0.01, $0.01, 0.99, 2, 2.00, etc.

Comment: @northpole that's a great website! Zoolander, it seems that the regex is correct, expect you have to escape some more thing (you can see exactly what on that regex website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
^\$?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*)(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?303ui)

The only thing that is is not matching is your third last example, it has a space before the dot. Is that valid?

**Edit:**

My frist solution has the restriction, that it would accept numbers starting with 0, like 001. This solution uses a negative lookahead to avoid this:

```
^\$?(?!0\d)(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*)(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?303ul)

**Solution without lookahead**

```
^\$?(?:0|[1-9]\d*|[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{1,3})*)(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

See it on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?303uo)

Answer (score 0):

```
^\$?(?:[1-9]\d?\d?(?:(?:,\d{3})*|(?:\d{3})*)|0)(?:\.\d\d?)?$
```

Altho I wouldn't use such strict input restrictions.